# Do references in c++ represent objects?

Tags: c++, reference

I am a beginner to c++.
I read it on internet [reference is the object](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/ref.html). My question regarding this, as one can represent primitives too through reference variable Ex- `int a=3;int &s=a;`, then where does the contradiction lie ?

Comment: "... as one can represent primitive objects too through reference variable..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, "object" does not only refer to class instances. An `int` variable is also called an object. It's an object of type `int`.

See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object

> An object, in C++, is a region of storage that has a size, an alignment, a storage duration, a lifetime, a type, a value, and (optionally) a name.

An `int` variable therefore is an object. Yes, `int` is a primitive type, but variables of primitive types are also called "objects."